# PHP named semaphores?

Tags: php, posix

I've been looking around but I can't seem to find any implementation of POSIX named semaphores for PHP. The only thing I see is SysV semaphores.

(2 questions)

Is there any way to access named semaphores from PHP currently?

Are there any plans for future releases of PHP?

Comment: Why would you need access to semaphores? PHP doesn't support threading...

Comment: @Byron: You can access the same named semaphore from different processes, not only threads.

Comment: I actually need to lock a file that both a PHP and a perl script write to. And there can be several instances of both the PHP and the perl script running. I also saw the flock() function but I think that one won't do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the short answer would be **NO**, from my "research" I found there isn't a POSIX named semaphores implementation currently in PHP.

Bob Fanger posted an interesting workaround to convert strings to SysV semaphore keys, the downside is you have to implement this same algorithm in every code you need the semaphore.

What I ended up doing, though, was using `flock()` on a lock file.

**PHP**

```
# open an exclusive lock
$lock = fopen('/path/to/file.lock', 'w');
flock($lock, LOCK_EX);

# edit a file
$f = fopen ('/path/to/file.txt', 'a');
fwrite($f, "append through PHP\n");
fclose($f);

# unlock
flock($lock, LOCK_UN);
fclose($lock);
```

**PERL**

```
use Fcntl qw(:flock);

# open an exclusive lock
open LOCK, '>/path/to/file.lock';
flock LOCK, LOCK_EX;

# edit a file
open FILE, '>>/path/to/file.txt';
print FILE "append through PERL\n";
close FILE;

# unlock
flock LOCK, LOCK_UN;
close LOCK;
```

I know the extra lock file might seem as an overkill but you can only use `LOCK_EX` on write mode, and sometimes I only needed to read the file.

**note:** `flock()` works as an advisory file locking mechanism, if any other program tries to modify the file without calling `flock()` it will succeed.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my "named" semaphore implementation, but i'm not sure if you're looking for a simple string to int converter.

```
/**
 * Generate a semaphore integer from a string/key
 *
 * @param string $identifier
 * @return int
 */
function sem_key($identifier) {
    $md5 = md5($identifier);
    $key = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 32; $i++) { 
        $key += ord($md5{$i}) * $i;
    }
    return $key;
}
```

Comment: Interesting workaround. I actually played around with the flock() function and it was exactly what I needed, but I appreciate your answer.

I'm new to StackOverflow (as you probably noticed). Is there any way to tag this question as "no longer in need of answer"? Or should I just mark your answer as "accepted answer"?

Comment: You should answer your own question with the solution you used. And mark your own answer as "accepted answer"

Comment: how great is possibility for collisions? there are also other processes running on the system which could clash with it?

Comment: @mpapec As far as I understand it, System V semaphores are shared between all processes, so there is always a chance of a collision. As long as you don't use other semaphores inside a semaphore-lock, this doesn't have to be a problem, the acquiring of the lock just takes longer.

Comment: At the first step, when $i == 0, zero is added to the $key. Thus, the first character of $md5 is disregarded which can cause collisions. Consider multiplying by $i + 1 instead:

 for ($i = 0; $i < 32; $i++) { 
        $key += ord($md5{$i}) * ($i + 1);
    }